# angular animation on button click works only the first time

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am not able to remove the animation class from the button.

**CODE**

```
.directive('animateTrigger', ['$animate', function ($animate) {

return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on('click', function () {
       elem.addClass("animated zoomIn")    
    });    
  $animate.removeClass(elem, "animated zoomIn")
  }    
}])
```

animation works only the first time.

Besides I tried this but no help

```
.directive('animateTrigger', function ($animate) {
      return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         elem.on('click', function () {
            $animate.addClass(elem, "animated zoomIn", function () {
              elem.removeClass("animated zoomIn")
              scope.$apply();
        });
      });
    }
  };
})
```